# translating a custom geometry in three,js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Three.js and 3D programming in general, but I am trying to get the horse from [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_horse) to move across the screen from a fixed camera.

The code that 'loads' the horse is here:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "models/animated/horse.js", function( geometry ) {

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
            vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
            morphTargets: true
            } ) );
            mesh.scale.set( 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 );
            scene.add( mesh );

            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );

            var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence( 'gallop', geometry.morphTargets, 30 );
                mixer.addAction( new THREE.AnimationAction( clip ).warpToDuration( 1 ) );

            } );
```

In my render function I can't increase the object's x and z poisition the same way I can with the camera's:

```
var radius = 600;
var theta = 0;
var prevTime = Date.now();

function render() {

theta += 0.1;
camera.position.x = radius * Math.sin( THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 ) );
camera.position.z = radius * Math.cos( THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 ) );

mesh.position.x = theta;
mesh.position.z = theta;
}
```

I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined` even though `mesh.position.x` returns a number when I enter it in the Javascript console. How can I translate this object?

Comment: are both your `camera` and the `mesh` defined as global variables?

Comment: @gaitat yes they are :/

Comment: Does `if ( mesh ) { mesh.position.x = theta; }`  work?

Comment: @WestLangley it does! thanks. i am confused as to how this works only with the conditional

Comment: somehow you are calling the `render()` before the model has been loaded

Answer (score 0):

`loader.load()` is an asynchronous method. That is why you specified a callback function. You need to make sure the model loads before you reference it.

One solution is to use this pattern in your render loop:

```
if ( mesh ) { mesh.position.x = theta; }
```

Another solution is to initiate `animate()` in the callback function.

three.js r.73